# uv unwraps to a weird shape

Tags: uv

Does anyone know why the top face unwraps weird? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi, to know why, it would help to have details about which UV unwrapping method was used

Answer (score 1):

first remove doubles just in case, and then mark a seam in that face and in where should have it as well, and then re-unwrap again